# Writing 1 million records to Excel file with 300 columns

Tags: java, apache-poi, excel-2007

I am using Apache POI Streaming API- SXSSFWorkbook to write data to excel file.
But Excel file is getting corrupted for more than 100 000 records with 300 columns generally if the size is greater then 100Mb. Is there any way for writing huge data to excel file.

```
class Test1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,  {


    SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);

    workbook.setCompressTempFiles(true);
    Sheet sheet = null;
    Row row = null;
    Cell cell = null;
    sheet =  workbook.createSheet("Demo1");
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Test1.xlsx");
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            row = sheet.createRow(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < 300; j++) {
                cell = row.createCell(j);
                cell.setCellValue(" row : "+i +" col: "+ j);
            }
        }


        workbook.write(outStream);

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        workbook.dispose();
        try {
            outStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Edit 1:

What I found is, it is not the problem with Apache POI Streaming Api.It is generating the file with 1 Million records. But Excel is not loading that file. It is giving 'There isn't enough memory to complete this action' error.

I am using Excel 2013 32 bit version which can use only up till 2GB of memory. The excel file I created with 100k records and 300 columns has file size 108MB. When I try to open this file in Excel it is taking up whole lot of System memory. As soon as the memory consumption reaches 1.7 MB Excel is giving an error.

What is the minimum configuration to load 1million rows generated using Apache Streaming API? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit 2:
If I open Excel file generated using Apache Streaming Api in zip format(by renaming .xlsx to .zip),size of the xml file in xl->worksheets folder is around 2GB for 100k records and 300 columns. Is there any way to reduce the size of this xml file.

Comment: What is the problem? I'm writing large XLSX files using SXSSF streaming and have not experienced problems. (Besides having enough disk space with output and tmp areas).

Comment: When I try to open the file using Excel 2007 it is showing 'Excel found unreadable content'. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you verify there is enough disk space? Is the same code generating a working Excel file whaen only generating some rows (e.g. < 100k)? Is it working with less columns (.e.g. < 256)?

Comment: Yes it is creating working excel file with 100k rows and 200 columns.
I have enough disk space. I am using jdk 1.8 and apche poi 3.14-final

Comment: Then, you are aware that XLSX format will only allow 1048576 rows with an excel file. So the maximum row number  (zero based index!) is 1048575. If you dow have more rows you need use different technics. E.g. start a new sheet.

Comment: But I couldnt even  write 100k records .

Comment: Can you suggest me how many records I can write per  Sheet. I need to write 1million records to Excel Workbook.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Never had tried generating more than about 100 to 120 columns myself. But a restriction at 255 columns max is not really surprising (had been this way with older Excel formats). Your observation that 100k rows with 200 columns is working fine, while 100k rows with 300 columns is failing, is a strong indicator of such a restriction.

Then you should be able to generate the 1 million (exactly 1048576) rows sheet with up to 255 columns.,For any extra rows and extra columns you will need to create extra sheets.

So, with your 300 columns target, you would generate sheet1 with the first 255 columns (or some less if there is reasonable logical grouping) and sheet2 with the other columns.

For more rows repeat the 2 sheets approach with a new pair of sheets until all rows have been generated.

BTW,
did you recognize that with using SXSSFWorkbook a rowAccessWindowSize of "1" is giving best performance?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Which office version are you using to open file with 1million rows and 100 columns. I am using Excel 2007 32bit version. If i try to open the file it is giving Not enough resources to display error message.

Comment: Personally using LibreOffice. But the error message sounds like your machine is too small for opening the file.

Comment: Can you share the system configuration details  which is used to load 1million records generated using Apache Streaming API.

Thanks.

Comment: 2 8core Xeon E5, 3GHz, 256GB main memory, 512GB swap, NetBSD 6

Comment: You really should not try generating such big Excel in the first place. I consider Excel to be something for human consumption - but nobody will be able reading or looking at 1 million rowsmaking sense out of it (and not onyl because it takes significant time for opening). All my true processing is using text files (CSV). The Excel is just for fulfilling customer request (and I simply generate it and verify it is OK. I'd assume, nobody on the customer side is trying to open the Excel. They are just storing it away for documentation.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)